# "Felix est rex is quem omnes cives amant". Is the pronoun "is" necessary?

Tags: syntax, pronouns

Considering the original phrase:

> The king who all citizens love is happy.
>
> (Portuguese: Feliz é o rei a quem todos os cidadãos amam.)

Here is a proposed Latin translation:

> Felix est rex is quem omnes cives amant

Is the pronoun "is" necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you got that *is* from. The original phrase, which seems to be from a [1845 book](https://archive.org/details/elementarygramma00khrich) of Latin exercises, does not has it. For instance, see [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dBNgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22Felix+est+rex+quem+omnes+cives+amant%22&source=bl&ots=dLRGZcXir3&sig=K1yrgvF7gfh_x9OQQOfUPgLz6HM&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSqYvPnLzcAhULK8AKHaIDChkQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%22Felix%20est%20rex%20quem%20omnes%20cives%20amant%22&f=false).

In any case, *is* as pronoun means "he", or as demonstrative, "this/that", so maybe the phrase with the *is* could be translated as

> Happy is he the king who all citizens love

or

> Happy is this/that king who all citizens love

Comment: Appreciated. The translation to latin I got is from someone who translated from the portuguese version. But any way, I couldn`t found a reason as well.

Comment: It could easily be *a happy king is he whom all citizens love* with *felix* fronted for emphasis.

Comment: In this context, where *is* agrees with the subject, I think *he* would be a less likely translation: *this/that* is better. It gives extra emphasis but it is optional. P.S. A defining relative clause (subjunctive) might be more appropriate here, in which case *is* is desirable: *felix est rex is quem omnes ament*.

Answer (score 0):

The best of Latin: the best of English: happy is the king; he (is), whom (quem) all citizens love. To omit "is" may be acceptable; but, the assertion becomes sloppy. Guys with the erudition of Cicero would not thank you.

Comment: I don't get this argument at all. The antecedent of the relative clause is _rex_.. Why does it need a demonstrative in apposition? What's sloppy about omitting it?

Comment: @Colin Fine: Here, "king" is being emphasised (possibly for a dramtic effect); HE, whom...Omit "si", which you may do, the emphasis is reduced; assertion is weakened.